# Word-spacing not working with @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

Does `@font-face` not support the `word-spacing` CSS property? It doesn't apply to my text when I use it in any browser.

Answer (score 2):

My [test](http://jsfiddle.net/LeLm5/) (an example from http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html with an added element where `word-spacing` is used) shows that `word-spacing` works just fine with `@font-face`. It’s a completely different property. Please post an example where you think it does not work.

Comment: I applied it to the h3 tag but it doesn't effect the text. `#content li h3{
        font-family:bebasneue;
        font-size:24px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        word-spacing:1px;
}`